# html css sort of work but messy implementation

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, responsive, custom-wordpress-pages

I created this footer in wordpress and it mostly works but the code is just ugly and not well structured.  I had a lot of problems with the image and text in the anchor tags.  Also, when the browser width gets very small the elements don't fall correctly on the page.  The email input ends up below the green background and in wordpress the icons /text in the anchor tags split to two lines.

How do I make this work and look cleaner so it's easier to maintain?

note:the media query is there because the wordpress plugin needed to be reveresed engineered a little bit with this approach.  Was having trouble with the background color white for html  around different blocks

```css
.myfooter{
  height:auto;
  background-color:white;
  padding: 0 2.87rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 961px) {.myfooter{
  padding:0 1.7rem;}
}

.cap{
  background-color:#538231;
}



.left input, .left label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:3vw;
    width:27vw;
    font-size:1vw;
}

.left input{
  height:1vw;
}

.left label{
  color:#c2d59b;
  padding-bottom:.5vw;
}

.left{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  background-color:#538231;
  height:5vw;
  padding-top:2vw;
  padding-bottom:5vw;
}

.myfooter h1{
  color:#b3d7f8;  /*#b6dde6;*/
  font-size:1.5vw;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0;
  margin-left:3vw;
  padding-top:2vw;
  
}

.right-div{
  width:40%;
  float:right;
  color:white;
  background-color:#538231;
  font-size:1vw;
  padding-left:10%;
  height:12vw;
  
}

.right-div div p a {
  text-decoration:none;
}

.right-div div p a:visited{
  color:white;
}

  
.last3{
  width:17vw;
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0!important;
  background-color:#538231;
  border:solid 1px white;
  margin-bottom:1vw!important;
}

.d3 p a{
  display:block;
  height:1.9635vw;
}

.footer-icons {
  padding: .25vw;
  width: 1.25vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left:.5vw;
  float:left;
}

.footer-icons:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.footer-txt{
  padding: .5vw 0 .5vw .5vw;
  font-size:1vw;
  line-height:1;
  float:left;
}


.submit-button {
  background-color: white!important; /* Green */
  border: none!important;
  color: black!important;
  padding: .5vw .5vw!important;
  text-align: center!important;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
  font-size: 1vw!important;
  height:2vw!important;
  width:5vw!important;
  line-height:1vw!important;
}

#email{
  padding:.5vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="myfooter">
   <div class="cap"><h1>Help create a sustainable and healthy town of Weston</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="left">
      <form name="message" method="post">
         <section>  
            <div style="float:left;">     
               <label for="email">Join our mailing list:</label>
               <input id="email" type="email"  name="email" placeholder="enter email">
               <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">   
            </div>
         </section>
      </form>
   </div>
   <div class="right-div">
      <div class="d3">   
         <p  class="last3">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1960906387454685">
               <img class="footer-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facebook-square-brands-green.png">
               <span class="footer-txt">Like us on Facebook</span>
            </a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="d3">
         <p class="last3">
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sustainablewestonactiongroup/">
               <img class="footer-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/instagram-brands-green.png">
               <span class="footer-txt">follow us on Instagram</span>
            </a>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="d3">
         <p id="4" class="last3">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Weston_SWAG">
               <img class="footer-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/twitter-square-brands-green.png">
               <span class="footer-txt">Retweet us on Twitter</span>
            </a>
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make this work and look cleaner then?

Comment: Yes! That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you trying using flexbox. I removed/condensed your code. Of course if you use SASS, you could wrap all the CSS in your myFooter class.

```
<div class="myFooter">
  <div class="left">
    <h3>Help create a sustainable and healthy town of Weston</h3>
    <form name="message" method="post">
      <section>  
          <label for="email">Join our mailing list:</label><input id="email" type="email"  name="email" placeholder="enter email">
          <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
      </section>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1960906387454685">
          <img class="foot-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/facebook-square-brands-green.png"><span class="foot-txt">Like us on Facebook</span>
        </a>

        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sustainablewestonactiongroup/">
          <img class="foot-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/instagram-brands-green.png
          "><span class="foot-txt">follow us on Instagram</span>
        </a>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/Weston_SWAG">
          <img class="foot-icons" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/twitter-square-brands-green.png"><span class="foot-txt">Retweet us on Twitter</span>
       </a>
  </div>
</div>

.myFooter{
  background: #538231;
  padding: 1.5em;
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.myFooter .left{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.myFooter .right{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.myFooter h3{
  color:#b3d7f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.myFooter label{
  display: block;
  color: #c2d59b
}

.myFooter input{
  padding: 3px 10px;
}

.myFooter .right a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.myFooter .right img{
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wvc2p63y/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the proper indenting on your HTML file can make a big difference in readability. Try indenting the children of your HTML tags to show that that content is "within" the tag.

As for your CSS classes, try out something like BEM, you can learn more about it here: http://getbem.com/introduction/

BEM is useful for creating CSS class names that mean something, rather than just simple variable names that can be forgotten in a week. After changing your class names to BEM, try sorting your classes in the CSS file by appearance on the page top to bottom, or alphabetically.

Comment: This is being done in wordpress hence the custom wordpress tag.  I've formated the html but it doesn't seem to be an option in wordpress. As new lines create <br> and other weird stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are trying to make your css look cleaner you should look into something like sass or scss. It provides a scaffolding structure to your css so it is easier to understand. It might end up looking something like this...

```
.right {
    width:40%;
    float:right;
    color:white;
    background-color:#538231;
    font-size:1vw;
    padding-left:10%;
    height:12vw;
    div {
        p {
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
                &:visited {
                    color:white;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this in wordpress so i'm not sure that's an option.  Besides this is a really simple page

Comment: You can definitely do it in wordpress, I do it for all my wordpress projects. [https://jointswp.com/] is a great wordpress theme to work off of that has scss already built-in.